# CSS doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using GitHub to host my site it worked normally for a while but after a while my browser stopped updating the CSS and JS files HTML files update normally. For others it works normally but not for me.

I have tried: CTRL+F5, CTRL+SHIFT+R, clearing cache.

Here is the source: https://github.com/Jakooob14/jakooob-site

The site: https://jakooob.ml

Comment: Most likely what you want is to implement some sort of "cache-busting" technique-- this is a catch-all term for methods that force the browser to fetch fresh versions of resources.  [Here is a CSS Tricks article on cache busting CSS](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/), but I imagine most of the techniques are relatively agnostic to other forms of resources.

Comment: Also, try in an incognito window.  If that doesn't work, then the issue is most likely not with your browser-- perhaps you haven't actually updated your files, or one of the servers Github uses to deliver content is misbehaving...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cool that sites like GitHub offer free hosting, but I'm not always clear how they manage caching of files. One thing you can do is add a query string to the URL, which will force the browser to fetch a fresh copy:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-index.css?v=1" />
```

The `?v=1` above should do the trick.

Comment: This worked thank you, but I'd need to update the ```?v=1``` to ```?v=2```, ```?v=2```, ```?v=3``` and so on right?

Comment: Generally yes-- ideally you would integrate this into some sort of build script.  Also, please remember to mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Ah yes thank you I will mark it as an answer I just need to wait for the cooldown thanks!

Comment: My strategy is to use a date string so I know when it was last updated: `?v=22.2.22`. Happy Twos Day.